# What is a supercongruence?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, congruences

I am very familiar to the congruences in modular arithemtic, But sometimes I can see questions related to supercongruences but I couldn't find any information about it on google.

Can someone explain what it is? and what is the difference with a classic congruence?

Comment: See http://mathoverflow.net/questions/26137/binomial-supercongruences-is-there-any-reason-for-them and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1596528/supercongruence-for-binomial-coefficients.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supercongruences are ordinary congruences modulo a power of a prime.

Comment: See https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/supercongruence#English